# MUI Select component menu takes 2 clicks to open when another Select component's menu is open

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I'm working on an app that has two dropdowns (Select components) displayed beside each other (I will refer to them as A and B).

Suppose A is open and the user wants to click and open B. I've noticed that by default, material UI requires the user to do this in two clicks; 1 click to close A, followed by 1 click to open B.

A similar issue was brought up in this thread for the Menu component: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/11243

It seems like the click event isn't bubbling up.

Is it possible to override this behavior?

My code:

```
import { InputLabel, MenuItem, FormControl, Select } from '@mui/material';

const Dropdown = ({ value, label, options, setter }) => {

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        const selectedValue = event.target.value;
        setter(selectedValue);
    };

    return (
        <FormControl
            variant='outlined'
            size="small"
            sx={{
                minWidth: "120px",
                backgroundColor: "#eb6060",
                borderRadius: "5px",
                border: "1px solid black",
                // Remove blue outline on dropdown when user clicks on dropdown
                '& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline': {
                    border: 'none',
                },
            }}
        >
            <InputLabel
                shrink={false} // prevent label from shrinking to top-left corner when user clicks on dropdown
                sx={{
                    // prevent blue highlight on label text when user clicks on dropdown
                    color: "black",
                    opacity: 0.6,
                    "&.Mui-focused": {
                        color: "black",
                        opacity: 0.6,
                    },
                    
                }}
            >
                {value === "" ? label : ""}
            </InputLabel>
            <Select
                onChange={handleChange}
                label={value === "" ? label : ""}
                value={value}
                onClose={() => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                      document.activeElement.blur();
                    }, 0);
                }}
                sx={{
                    "&:hover": {
                        backgroundColor: "#b34b4b",
                    },
                    "&.Mui-focused": {
                        backgroundColor: "#b34b4b",
                    },
                }}
            >
                {options.map((option) => (
                    <MenuItem
                        key={option.code}
                        value={option.code}
                        sx={{
                            // Remove keyboard focus highlight on dropdown options
                            "&.Mui-focusVisible": {
                                backgroundColor: "white",
                            },
                            // Add hover highlight on dropdown options
                            "&.MuiMenuItem-root:hover": {
                                backgroundColor: "#D3D3D3",
                            }
                        }}
                    >
                        {option.alias}
                    </MenuItem>
                ))}
            </Select>
        </FormControl>
    );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

Comment: Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new

Comment: Sure thing! Here's the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-bassi-4pfzhw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bit hacky but I don't know other approach. How the dropdown works: when you open it, an invisible backdrop with a high z-index is added covering everything except the options, and when its clicked the dropdown is closed, that's why you can click anywhere in the page and it will close because you are clicking the invisible backdrop. What I did was to add a z-index higher than the backdrop, so the dropdown stays in front and becomes clickable. But only this would have both dropdowns opened in the same time, so I added a code in the onOpen, to click the current backdrop and close it before opening the new one:

https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-black-mr6c52?file=/src/Dropdown.js

**Dropdown.js**

```
import { InputLabel, MenuItem, FormControl, Select } from "@mui/material";

const Dropdown = ({ value, label, options, setter }) => {
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const selectedValue = event.target.value;
    setter(selectedValue);
  };

  return (
    <FormControl
      variant="outlined"
      size="small"
      sx={{
        minWidth: "140px",
        backgroundColor: "#eb6060",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        border: "1px solid black",
        zIndex: 1350, //  zIndex to be on top of backdrop
        "& .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
          border: "none"
        }
      }}
    >
      <InputLabel
        shrink={false} // prevent label from shrinking to top-left corner when user clicks on dropdown
        sx={{
          // prevent blue highlight on label text when user clicks on dropdown
          color: "black",
          opacity: 0.6,
          "&.Mui-focused": {
            color: "black",
            opacity: 0.6
          }
        }}
      >
        {value === "" ? label : ""}
      </InputLabel>
      <Select
        onChange={handleChange}
        label={value === "" ? label : ""}
        value={value}
        //  Click on current backdrop to close the current dropdown
        onOpen={() => {
          document.querySelector(".MuiModal-backdrop")?.click();
        }}
        onClose={() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            document.activeElement.blur();
          }, 0);
        }}
        sx={{
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: "#b34b4b"
          },
          "&.Mui-focused": {
            backgroundColor: "#b34b4b"
          }
        }}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <MenuItem
            key={option.code}
            value={option.code}
            sx={{
              // Remove keyboard focus highlight on dropdown options
              "&.Mui-focusVisible": {
                backgroundColor: "white"
              },
              // Add hover highlight on dropdown options
              "&.MuiMenuItem-root:hover": {
                backgroundColor: "#D3D3D3"
              }
            }}
          >
            {option.alias}
          </MenuItem>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

Comment: It took me a while but I realized that this change results in being unable to close a dropdown by clicking on it (that is, closing a dropdown by clicking on its label rather than outside of the dropdown or on one of the menu items)

I did some research and I think I found that MUI core's Select component does not have this issue, so I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

> It took me a while but I realized that this change results in being unable to close a dropdown by clicking on it (that is, closing a dropdown by clicking on its label rather than outside of the dropdown or on one of the menu items)

I also faced this kind of issue and i figured out a simple solution:
You need to control open/closed state of select using useState hook. Here is updated CodeSandbox example forked from [Paulo Fernando](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19223586/paulo-fernando)

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dry-tree-xyqgpd

UPD:
Found another issue related to this solution:
Somehow we are able to open two select items at once (as shown on screenshot below)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge9mn.png)

The solution is also pretty simple. You need to rewrite onOpen prop in Select component as following:

```
onOpen={() => {
  [...document.querySelectorAll(".MuiModal-backdrop")].forEach((el) => el.click());
  setOpen(true);
}}
```

UPD #2:
Also setting z-index of FormControl to a high number can cause overlaping over other elements on the page. We can fix this by changing FormControl's z-index to 2, and by changing backdrop's z-index via MenuProps prop in Select component as following:

```
MenuProps={{
  style: { zIndex: 1 }
}}
```